# how to union 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

using c#4 having 2 dictionaries of type

```
<string,List<int>>



dictionary1 = [ { "key1" , [ 1, 2, 3]} ,
                 { "key2" , [ 1, 2, 4 , 6]}
              ]
```

I want to union with dictionary2

```
dictionary2 = [ { "key0" , [ 1, 2, 3]} ,
                 { "key2" , [ 1, 2, 3, 5 , 6]} 
              ]
```

so to get =>

```
dictionary1 + dictionary2  = [ { "key1" , [ 1, 2, 3]} ,
                 { "key2" , [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]},
                 { "key0" , [ 1, 2, 3]}
              ]
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: @Candide It does not look like an answer the OP is looking for, because he is looking for a two-way merge.

Comment: By the way, do you allow duplicates inside the list of integers? (I mean `{ "key1" , { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 }}`.)

Comment: If you want a LINQ approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792130/1149773

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the so-called "duplicate" question seems to be referring to lists of dictionaries rather than 2 dictionaries

Comment: I agree @SamIam, this question needs to merge values as well as the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = 
   dictionary1.Union(dictionary2)
    .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(v => v.Value).Distinct().ToList());
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple loop with `Enumerable.Union`?:

```
foreach (var kv in dictionary2)
{
    List<int> values;
    if (dictionary1.TryGetValue(kv.Key, out values))
    {
        dictionary1[kv.Key] = values.Union(kv.Value).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary1.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Haddar: fyi, edited my answer since my first version was buggy.

Comment: I took @L.B example, 10X