# Iterating over a List<IDictionary<string,object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to compute a merged dictionary based on an input of `List<IDictionary<string,object>>`.

Typically this would be the combination of the explicit `merged_dataset` copy followed by a `foreach`:

```
var merged_dataset = my_datasets.SelectMany(dict => dict)
             .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
             .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
foreach (var item in merged_dataset)
  [...logic based on item.Value.Distinct()...]
```

Is there a way to do the above "on-the-fly", without an explicit call to `ToDictionary` which constructs `merged_dataset` and somewhat like a `Enumerable.Zip` with two datasets, but with a `List` of N-datasets as input ?

In the end I would end up with:

```
var iterator = my_datasets.SelectMany(dict => dict)
         .GroupBy(dict => dict.Key)[...missing ToList...]
foreach ((string key, List<object> values) in iterator)
```

References:

- [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)
- [c# merging multiple dictionaries into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140066/c-sharp-merging-multiple-dictionaries-into-one)

Comment: Just replace `ToLookup` with `GroupBy` and remove `ToDictionary`?

Comment: Missing `ToList()`

Comment: Question is a bit unclear to me still. "without expicit merged_dataset" you can just replace that variable with expression itself in foreach statement.

Comment: @Evk Let me know if the question is a bit less unclear. Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to have a lot of overhead from looking up in the `List<Dictionary>` for all the keys? What is your goal for avoiding `ToDictionary`? Also, why not put `Distinct` in `ToDictionary`, or just use the result of `ToLookup` directly?

Comment: Apparently you don't realize that `GroupBy` does essentially the same thing as `ToLookup()` and has to pre-merge all the keys before it can return a single group, so I don't think that does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to implement a multi-dictionary that essentially maps `List<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>>` to `Dictionary<TKey,IEnumerable<TValue>>`. Here is a sample implementation, but because it computes everything as requested, it is not very efficient for repeated operations. If the list is small, and you are just enumerating once, it may be more efficient than pre-creating a new `Lookup` and enumerating that, but probably not.

```
public class MultiDictionary<TKey,TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>> {
    List<Dictionary<TKey,TValue>> dictionaries;

    public MultiDictionary(List<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> src) {
        dictionaries = src;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys => dictionaries.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct();
    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values => dictionaries.SelectMany(d => d.Values);

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => dictionaries.Any(d => d.ContainsKey(key));
    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value) => dictionaries.Any(d => d.ContainsValue(value));

    public IEnumerable<TValue> this[TKey key] => dictionaries.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(key)).Select(d => d[key]);
    public int Count => Keys.Count();

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>>.GetEnumerator()
        => Keys.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>>(k, this[k])).GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

One way to improve the performance would be to create a `Lookup` mapping all the keys to the dictionaries that contain them, but then you might as well create a merged `Lookup` that combines all the key value pairs.